# In 17.10 all new windows start maximized is there a way to disable that?

Tags: 17.10, window, maximized

Every application that opens a new window will create a maximized window and I don't like that. Is there a way to start applications normally? like the previous window size

Ubuntu 17.10
Gnome 3.26.2 on Wayland